# How to search public posts in Graph API v2.3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search public posts in graph api v2.3 using asp.net c#.
kindly reply me as soon as possible thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since Graph API v2.0 this is no longer possible. Please read the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> Public Post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

Please don't ask for a workaround. Facebook restricted this on (their) purpose.

Comment: that last sentence is not a bad idea. they ALWAYS ask if there is another way :)